# Execute an on-demand web job from my ASP.NET website?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

Right now I have a web job that is Continuos with "Always On". This webjob listens for queue messages and performs actions. Everything works fine but I have to pay for every minute the web job "listens" to commands, isn't it?

I have seen that you can also run a web job on demand but I haven't found any example code on how to execute an on demand web job.

Background: I am running a web crawler inside a web job that receives the URL that should be crawled from a message queue. I would like to minimize the costs.

How can I execute an on demand web job from my ASP.NET website?

Thanks

Comment: What Pricing Tier are you hosting this ASP.NET website that you'd like to call it from?

Comment: Are you deploying the WebJob with this ASP.NET site you want to call it from?

Comment: No, I am deploying them separately.

Comment: Are you deploying to the same Web Hosting Plan as the ASP.NET site?

Comment: Yes, same web hosting plan, but different web apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your site is already running on a Standard Instance and the WebJob is running in the same Web Hosting Plan at your site, you are not paying anything additional as both the WebJob (and its host site) and the site itself are running on the same VMs.

You can enable (or leave) Always On enabled and not incur any additional costs. Turning off Always On will not save you any money and as you are aware, it is required for a Continuous WebJob to run properly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Also, take a look at the WebJobs API for invoking an on-demand web job. https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API.

Comment: Yes, forgot to add that too since that was one of the things being asked for too. Thanks Rick :)